# MOSFET pass short spike during power up

Tags: power, power-electronics

I discovered one feature. I've designed circuit for pulse generation and I discovered that it always pass one spike during power up. The circuit is consist of two sections. PMOS for Enable and PMOS for Pulse generation (in the picture both are OFF) When I turn on Power Supply output. It passes short spike.

[image]

[image]

Even if I have only one transistor or if I'm using NMOS, or analog switch (ADG1411) the effect is always the same. I have spike on the load. It happens even in my prototype board.

It look's like some parasitic capacitance. I noticed that if set Cjo = 0, there is no spike, but it's impossible in reality.

Am I right? If I'm right so how to deal with that feature? Is there any option to avoid spikes on the output when I power up device? Relays, other circuits for MOS?

Comment: add supply cap, some minimal power entry filter (eg ferrite and a small value resistor to damp) -> bring up power slower?

Comment: You're right, when I have slower power supply (20ms rising edge) then there is no spike.